# Improve webm quality when accelerating video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, webm

I have a `.webm` video that I want to accelerate to timelapse it. My original `.webm` video is 1280x720 and has a very good quality, but when I accelerate it with `FFMPEG` the quality is really bad (even when the resolution stays the same). This is the command I'm using:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i test.webm -c:v libvpx-vp9 -filter:v "setpts = 0.1 * PTS" out.webm -threads 3
```

If I try the same with a `.mp4` video the quality remains the same as the original video, but with `.webm` it just seems to destroy the video quality. I tried changing the bitrate with `-minrate 1M -maxrate 1M -b:v 1M` but doesn't improve anything.

[This](https://mega.nz/#!vsRXBTrb!dD-tmqd8AEHkGS-J8iW6kVTmodpQ-w09DUHtd1C6Y5A%20%22%22) is the video I'm converting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VPx encoders in FFmpeg default to a bitrate of 200 kb/s. Try CRF method instead:

```
ffmpeg -i test.webm -vf "setpts=0.1*PTS" -c:v libvpx-vp9 -crf 25 -b:v 0 -threads 3 out.webm
```

Experiment with the CRF value till you get an acceptable tradeoff between size and quality. Lower numbers produce better quality but larger files.

Comment: Your exact command makes `FFMPEG` crash, I don't know why. But I used it like this: `ffmpeg.exe -i test.webm -c:v libvpx-vp9 -filter:v "setpts = 0.1 * PTS" out.webm -threads 3 -crf 0 -b:v 0` and no quality improvement at all :/

Comment: The way you used it, the CRF no longer affects the output file. The parameters have to be placed *before* the output file name, Only global options can be placed anywhere. Get a recent [copy](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) and try.

Comment: What's the framerate of the webm?

Comment: Great! Has to download the x64 version (I was using x86) and worked perfectly, the quality is so much better!